# Why my query is not returning all the data?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I'm trying to make a query in order to Join two tables in PostgreSQL by using a column (id) in common (column named "cliente").

My try is as follow (the full join is because the amount of IDs in the table 2 are not equal than on the table 1):

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.pais,t1.cliente,t1.documento_entrega,t1.canal_entrega,t1.centro,t1.id_drv,
t1.drv,t1.id_uen,t1.uen,t1.id_agencia, t1.agencia,t1.ruta,t1.dias_semana_real,
t1.dias_icaro,t1.adherencia,t1.excepciones_t3_t4,t1.d2,t1.fuera_ruta_volumen_cartones,
t1.fuera_ruta_volumen_hectolitros, t1.latitud, t1.longitud, t1.estatus, t1.icaro_fecha, 
t1.fecha_reparto,t1.fecha_salida_icaro,t1.fecha_carga,t1.hora_carga,t2.modelo_venta
     
FROM (SELECT id,pais,cliente,documento_entrega,canal_entrega,centro,id_drv,drv,id_uen,uen,
id_agencia,agencia,ruta,dias_semana_real, dias_icaro, adherencia, excepciones_t3_t4, d2, 
fuera_ruta_volumen_cartones,fuera_ruta_volumen_hectolitros, latitud, longitud, estatus, icaro_fecha, 
fecha_reparto, fecha_salida_icaro, fecha_carga,hora_carga, row_number () over (partition BY cliente 
ORDER BY cliente) AS rn FROM reporting_services.out_mx_log_icaro_fuera_ruta)t1
     
FULL JOIN (SELECT id, cliente, centro, modelo_venta, fecha, fecha_carga, hora_carga
, row_number () over (partition BY cliente ORDER BY cliente) as rn FROM 
reporting_services.out_mx_log_icaro_modelo_servicio_entrega) t2 on t1.cliente = t2.cliente AND t1.rn 
= t2.rn;
```

the problem here is that this query just shows me the data in the column "modelo_venta" that comes from the table 2 (this column is actually what I need to get from the join in the both tables), but all the other columns empty

Any idea? what could be wrong with my query?

Thanks by the way and have a good day.

Comment: What rdbms are you using? Edit question to show sample data as text table.

Answer (score 0):

Does both tables contain same number of rows for each clients? Even does those have same number of clients? Please check you have used row_number () over (partition BY cliente ORDER BY cliente) to join both tables along with the cliente.

Row_number() might not be same in this both cases. If possible please share sample data for further analysis.